# Can't start debugger in PowerGUI

Tags: powershell, powergui

I am using the PowerGUI Script Editor 1.7.1.702, and trying to start debugger, but I get such error message:

> Cannot find a provider with name
>   'Remove-PSBreakPoint -BreakPoint
>   $bE4078E3092DF4dd9A469F3DC0CBB505C;Remove-Variable
>   vE4078E3092DF4dd9A469F3DC0CBB505C;Remove-Variable
>   bE4078E3092DF4dd9A469F3DC0CBB505C;

This happens on this line:

```
Write-Host $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

I am working with PowerShell v2.

Comment: What version of v2? CTP3?

-Oisin

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to the RTM version of PowerShell 2.0 here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929